# NoMethodError in StylesController#new undefined method `styles' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im getting this error with ruby on rails. I made a scaffold called Style that has a title and a description(string and text), a User session with the ruby gem devise and a model called category that i added to style with `add_category_id_to_styles`. 
I changed the

```
def new 
@style = Style.new
end
```

to

```
def new
@style = current_user.styles.build
end
```

in the style controller and now its giving me the undefined method 'styles' for nil:NillClass. Does any of you know why is giving me this error?

Comment: current_user will be null till you login.

Comment: Should i make a condition then? Thanks

Comment: In this case, current_user is null. which means you did not login. yes, you can check `if current_user.present?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise provides you with the method `#user_signed_in?` to check if the current user is signed in. If yes then you have access to `#current_user`. So you can have:

```
def new
  @style = user_signed_in? ? current_user.styles.build : Style.new
end
```

Of course you can check `current_user.present?` directly too but I think `#user_signed_in?` conveys the intention better.